# What does "basic computational steps" mean in the spec for Java class ForkJoinTask?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have been using Java7's Fork/Join concurrency framework, and it works well. I finally got around to reading the API's javadoc for ForkJoinTask, and it contains this paragraph:

> > ForkJoinTasks should perform relatively small amounts of computation. Large tasks should be split into smaller subtasks, usually via recursive decomposition. As a very rough rule of thumb, a task should perform more than 100 and less than 10000 **basic computational steps**, and should avoid indefinite looping. If tasks are too big, then parallelism cannot improve throughput. If too small, then memory and internal task maintenance overhead may overwhelm processing.

I understand all that, except for the bold text. What exactly is a "basic computational step"? Is it a generic computer science term, or is it specific to Java? How does it relate to byte code, lines of source code, source code statements, etc..?

An example might be as useful as a formal definition. Can anyone conjure up a few lines of Java and then break it down into to the associated "basic computational steps"?

Answer (score 1):

A basic step that can be directly evaluated, as opposed to an instruction which requires you to solve 10 other things before you evaluate it.  Or, simplest unit of work.  I would guess that in literal terms, computational steps refers to simple instructions in java bytecode.  As this explains, it's just a general method for describing how big a chunk of work is:

From http://coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html

A Java™ Fork-Join Calamity

Do you wonder why > 100, < 10k computational steps?

> 100 has to do with the work stealing problem. All forked Tasks go into the same deque making other threads search for work. When the threads encounter contention they back off and look somewhere else. Since there is no work anywhere else they try the same deque again, and again, and again until the forking thread finally finishes the work all by itself. You can see the proof by downloading the source code for Class LongSum.java below. Hence, run slow or there will be no parallelism.
>
> 10k has to do with the join() problem. Since the F/J framework cannot do pure Task Management (see Faulty Task Manager, above) with Tasks actually waiting independently of threads when they call join(), the framework has to create “continuation threads” to avoid a halt. There can only be a limited time before it all falls apart. Hence, run fast or die.

Comment: Thanks. I am already familiar with that article, but I don't see that it contains a definition/explanation of the phrase "basic computational steps" as used in the Javadoc spec for ForkJoinTask.

Comment: I guess I was trying to reason that if it were a well-defined term, you would get a boatload of definitions and uses when you googled it... which you don't.  So it's left open for the reader to interpret.  I believe it's more about knowing that the units of work are of similar size, than about knowing exactly how many assembler or bytecode instructions that that unit of work corresponds to.